# Laravel 4 - Soft delete and foreign Key reference

Tags: laravel-4

What is the best approach to do, for example:

I have a city that has many persons relationship.

If, for any reason i need to delete a city (using soft delete), then some persons may lost the city_id reference. This make the Laravel show an error message "Trying to get property of non-object".

**I need that the persons that has lost the city reference may be displayed without errors.**

When i write something like

```
echo isset($person->city) ? $person->city->name : '';
```

It works but looks a little ugly to me.

When i just write

```
echo $person->city->name;
```

I get a "Trying to get property of non-object" message because the city was deleted.

How does Laravel handle this?

Comment: The query that laravel uses to attach the cities object to your person object will check that the delete_at field is not null if it is null then the row has been soft deleted and will not appear in the results. To get round this you do the messy bit.

Comment: Thanks @MattBurrow. Maybe i need build it in a different way. Using some field like "status: enum('active','inactive')" in the cities table  to provide a maner that show legacy "deleted" city in the html datagrid persons, and hide inactive cities in the cities datagrid

Comment: You can include the soft deleted results in the query with the use of `withTrashed()` on your relation method. This will include all soft deleted models i.e. cities in your case. Then this will allow you to use `$person->city->name`.

Comment: Wow! You just save my day now heheh. Problem elegant solved with withTrashed(). I have some models that need keep legacy references so it will make easy. A good day for you.

Comment: I will add as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all models and soft deleted models, add the following to the relation method of cities in your Person model;

```
public function cities(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Cities\Model\Path')->withTrashed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's work fine @MattBurrow. Exactly what i needed. In my case i just change hasMany to belongsTo.

Models/Person.php

```
class Person extends \Eloquent {

    public function city(){
        return $this->belongsTo('City')->withTrashed();
    }
}
```